# PHP error variable error: Notice: Use of undefined constant FirstName - assumed 'FirstName'

Tags: php

```
foreach ($array as $row){
    $forEachCount++; //increment counter

    // naming logic
    if (empty($row['DisplayName'])) { // if there is no DisplayName
        if (empty($row['FirstName'])) { // show lastname
            $block[] = "<div class='block'>".$row['LastName']."</div>\n";
        }

        else { //show first + last if no display name
            $block[] = "<div class='block'>".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."</div>\n";
        }

    } else { // show display name
        $block[] = "<div class='block'>".$row['DisplayName']."</div>\n";
    }
}
```

What looks wrong in this code? The sort works fine when there's only a last name, or a display name. It only doesn't work when there's no display name so it concatenates the First + Last.

Comment: whats the result of var_dump($row['FirstName']);

Comment: Usually that message only displays if there's no quotes around the word. Are you sure the message comes from this block of code?

Comment: The problem is not in this section of code. But somewhere I'll bet you have `$row[FirstName]` (note the lack of quotes)

Comment: @aynber  that was the answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh haha we said the same thing 3 seconds apart :D

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to enclose the variable in `''` in one spot.
`['FirstName']`, not `[FirstName]`.

Thanks @aynber, @rjdown!